# how can I add a decimal ,2 charaters in from right, with php - keeping it as number type?

Tags: php, integer

I want to make 00026055 into 260.55. The following code does not work

```
echo number_format("00026055",2,".");
```

Answer (score 0):

[`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) is just a formatter so it leaves your data unchanged unless you are truncating decimals.

You need to perform a division preferably with [`bcdiv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php):

```
echo bcdiv( '00026055', '100', 2 );
```

or if precision does not matter to you then:

```
echo (int)'00026055' / 100;
```

Comment: Thank you, Can I turn it to a float in the next step?